# Python df to database float numbers unexpectedly rounded

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I have dataframe that contains 26 columns. the column types are float64, int64, datetime and object. I insert this df to database. however the float64 columns unexpectedly rounded as i see in the database.

'''

```
    query = config['query']['insert_output_query']  
    #query = insert into schema.table values(:1,:2,:3,...,:25,:26)
    db_cursor.executemany(query, df.values.tolist())
    db_connection.commit()
```

'''

i succesfully inserted the df to database but how i can handle unexpectedly rounding problem.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share some sample data which is both within the df, and within the db ..? And the column data type within the db.

Comment: sure, the samples from df.column --> 0, 0.85, 0.818, 0.125, 0.667, 1, same column seems to be just  0 and 1

Comment: If the data type within the DB is not `INT`, then perhaps, the number part and the fractional part should be separated by a comma rather than a dot. `SELECT TO_CHAR( '0.8512'  ,'fm999G999G990D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
  FROM dual ` might help.

Comment: sorry for late response, firstly thank you for your interest. I tried your advice but it did not work. still there are just 1 and 0 in the db column. when i tried to your query, the 0 s and 1 s seems to be 0.00 and 1.00 --  in dataframe i convert this column from float to str and db column from float to varchar(50), however the db column still keep whole values as 0.0

Comment: i find the problem. i created the table column as float but as i understand if i would not assigned the number of bits, a column which is type float keeps 1 digit. but when i assigned the column type as float(64)  it keeps the decimal and fractional part.

Comment: Nice catch and work, Keep on going !

Answer (score 1):

i find the problem. i created the table column as float but as i understand if i would not assignedthe number of bits, a column which is type float keeps 1 digit. but when i assigned the column type as float(64)  it keeps the decimal and fractional part.